# Hashmap inside a hashmap with arraylist

Tags: java, hashmap

**Declaration:-**

private static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList>> parentMap = new HashMap<>();
private static HashMap<String, ArrayList> childMap = new HashMap<>();

**How do I want to store data in hashmap?**

```
"India":
        "EmployeeName":[A,B,C]
        
"China":
        "EmployeeName":[D,E,F]
```

**Methods used:-**

```
public static ArrayList<String> getMap(String parentkey, String childKey) {
    return parentMap.get(parentkey).get(childKey);
}


public static ArrayList<String> setMap(String parentkey, String childKey, String value) {
    childMap.computeIfAbsent(childKey, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
    parentMap.put(parentkey, childMap);
    return getMap(parentkey, childKey);
}

setMap("India", "EmployeeName", "A")
setMap("India", "EmployeeName", "B")
setMap("India", "EmployeeName", "C")
setMap("China", "EmployeeName", "D")
setMap("China", "EmployeeName", "E")
setMap("China", "EmployeeName", "F")
```

**How data get stored and printed in hashmap while fetchng from getMap method:**

```
System.out.println("India" + getMap("India").get("EmployeeName"));
System.out.println("China" + getMap("China").get("EmployeeName"));

"India" [A,B,C,D,E,F]   
"China" [A,B,C,D,E,F]
```

Whilst i know keeping the childKey name unique would do thejob for me but I wish to keep the same childKey name under each parentkey name and store the respecive value in arraylist.

Any solution to my problem is welcome.

Comment: in your `setMap` method, what is `childMap`? Why does it already exists (and even static)? You need to use `childmap = parentMap.computeIfAbsent(...);`. Otherwise you use the same childMap everywhere which explains your output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you keep reusing the same `childMap`, regardless of which `parentKey` is being used. You need to look up the respective child map when adding values.

That means that `childMap` should be a local variable, nothing more. Delete your `private static HashMap<String, ArrayList> childMap`.

Try this:

```
public static ArrayList<String> setMap(String parentkey, String childKey, String value) {
  HashMap<String, ArrayList> childMap = parentMap.computeIfAbsent(parentkey, k->new HashMap<>());
  childMap.computeIfAbsent(childKey, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
  return getMap(parentkey, childKey);
}
```

[Proof that this works](https://ideone.com/sMelyE)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion, don't have generic types and dont have static params

```
private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> parentMap = new HashMap<>(); 
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> childMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Try to replace this method

```
public ArrayList<String> setMap(String parentkey, String childKey, String value) {
    childMap.putIfAbsent(childKey, new ArrayList<>()); // inserts a key only if the key is not already present
    childMap.get(childKey).add(value); // puts the value in the existing key and 
    
    if (!parentMap.containsKey(parentkey)) { // puts in the parent map only if not present. 
        parentMap.put(parentkey, childMap);
    }
}
```

Since the childmap is referenced already, No need to put again.

Comment: why is there no call to `parentMap.get` in case there's already a childmap for it? And why should `childMap` be a field and not a local variable?

Comment: @f1sh, there is no need to use get method, since childmap is a global variable and parent map has the reference to the global variable -> changing childMap is reflected directly in parentMap

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I will do it in more "OOP way" so that you can benefit from static typing. Something like:

```
import java.util.List;
class Employee{
    String name;
    String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}


public class CompanyBranch{
    String national;
    List<Employee> employees;

    List<String> getEmployeeAllName(){
        return employees.stream().map(Employee::getName).toList();
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not solve any of the problems that OP has.

Comment: May be I'm new to answer SO question but what I've given him is fishing rod not fish.
And the problem I see here is that he is coding Java in "Python ways". Maybe I'm misunderstanding...

Comment: yes, an answer should be the fish, cooked and deboned. Comments are good for leading the OP to their own answer.

Comment: @matt Oh I didn't know that. I'll learn from this